# Showing existence of Linear transformation such that $T(v)\neq0$, for any non zero vector v

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm trying to prove this:

> Let $v$ be a non-zero vector of a Vector space $V$ of finite dimension, given any non-zero vector space, prove that exists a Linear Transformation such that   $T(v)\neq0$

My thinking: I think that the linear transformation must be defined as $T:V\to V$, and I should somehow guarantee that I can always define an isomorphism in V (which is my Transformation) and because $v\neq0\,$ then because $T$ is injective this must happen $T(v)\neq0$ . But I don't how to guarantee that.

Comment: Take $T(av)=av$ and $T(w)=0$ whenever $w\neq v$

Comment: If we don't know the codomain of the linear transformation, this isn't true.

Comment: the OP says that $T:V\to V$

Comment: He says that he thinks it should be defined that way, but that is not specified in the question statement.

Comment: Yeah, probably they don't say how it should be defined in order for the student to make sense out the question and guarantee that such transformation always exists. As a I said and agreeing with the answer provided if I define and Isomorphism between V it should get the job done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about $\xi : V \to V, x \mapsto x$ ?

Comment: Nice answer N.H.!

Comment: @CésarRosendo : glad to help you.